# Задать изображение через URL в библиотеку Imagesearch

Tags: python, opencv

Всем привет.

Пытаюсь засунуть в функцию imagesearch изображение через URL. Не получается.

```
img = Image.open(urlopen("https://a.radikal.ru/a20/2004/8d/b8f9fb9101b1.jpg"))


pos = imagesearch("./RFOnlineScriptA/Templates/StartingPoint.jpg")
if pos[0] != -1:
    print("StartingPoint found in position : ", pos[0], pos[1])

else:
    print("StartingPoint not found")
```

Вот исходный вариант, как вставить img в функцию imagesearch? Если я пишу вот так:

```
pos = imagesearch(img)
```

то выдает ошибку https://prnt.sc/s2b6f5

Помогите пожалуйста, не хочу делать это через image.save() и писать путь.

Сама библиотека https://github.com/drov0/python-imagesearch

---

Через open cv также не получается

```
url = r'https://a.radikal.ru/a20/2004/8d/b8f9fb9101b1.jpg'
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# for testing
cv2.imshow('image',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()



pos = imagesearch(image)
if pos[0] != -1:
    print("StartingPoint found in position : ", pos[0], pos[1])

else:
    print("StartingPoint not found")
```

Comment: Что такое `imagesearch`?

Comment: @hedgehogues https://github.com/drov0/python-imagesearch

Comment: Так у вас проблема с opencv. Вы его поставили?

Comment: @hedgehogues opencv стоит, если я его включаю в список импортирующиъся библиотек, то ошибка остается. Сам imagesearch у меня работает  в исходном варианте, который я указал в вопросе. С ним проблем нет. У меня не получается засунуть в аргумент изображения ф-ии imagesearch что-то что не является путем к файлу.

Comment: Как вы ставили opencv?

Comment: Пробовали только с помощью opencv читать изображение?

Comment: @hedgehogues ставил отсюда https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ через консоль устанавливал. Только через open cv не пробовал,сейчас посмотрю попробую

Comment: @hedgehogues Та же ошибка была с таким кодом, при этом изображение считалось корректно и открылось. КОд добавил в тему выше

Comment: не могу код нормально в комментарий вставить.. Добавил в тему

Comment: У вас opencv не доустановлен

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html